# Key input line, picks noise up from 220V lines and automatically triggers

Tags: microcontroller, emi-filtering

I made an IR repeater board which records an IR command from a remote control and emits it every time an external key is pressed. It is used as an alternate remote control for a projector so the main remote control is not used every time.

While the device worked correctly on my desk with short wires, It got auto-trigger problems on the field which somehow was obvious. I'm seeking methods to eliminate this problem. The key input on the microcontroller is triggered all the time without any physical push on the actual key.

Here is the diagram:

[image: Diagram for the device]

The device is located on ceilings to be close to the projector IR receiver. A momentary key (SW1, J2 on schematic) is connected to the board using a long cable to be in reach of an operator.

Here is the schematic:
[image: The schematic]

So it seems I'm making a 2.5m antenna to pick up all the noise here and there. How can I eliminate this? I'm thinking about a series resistor, or an external pull-up on the MCU pin but I don't know the value or even if this methods work at all.

Comment: It's actually not the 220@50Hz that's the issue, it's transient spikes on the line that will emit enough radiation to mis-trigger. The fix is easy: put a ferrite bead (or two) on the long signal wire just before the device. they are the heavy inch-long cylinders you've probably asked yourself "what's that for?" at some point. You can snag one from an old USB cable, some DC wall warts, or order them on amazon. you can also/additionally wrap the signal wire with Al foil or copper tubing to shield it from emi/rf.